# Displaying an array of objects, one at a time through a single dialog... instead of several dialogs

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my application I have a list of questions stored in an ArrayList, and I want to display a dialog that shows one question, and then continues to the next one after the question is answered. The way that I'm currently doing it (iterating through a loop) hasn't been working because it just layers all of the dialogs on top of one another all at once which causes a host of other issues. What I'm looking for is a way to still iterate through the questions, but just change the layout of the dialog each time until it has finished each question in the list. Can anyone give me a good pointer for how to get this going?

Comment: Why use Dialogs? You could just create a View and change its content.

Comment: I use dialogs because the current view is relevant to the questions being answered, and performs other operations after the questioning part has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that takes title and message as parameters and shows a dialog.

```
showDialog(String title, String message){ // Show dialog code here}
```

Within that dialog's answer button's listener call another function (showQuestion(currentQuestion)) that iterates the arrayList till it is over

```
int currentQuestion=0;
ArrayList<QuestionObject> questionList;

showQuestion(int i){
  if(i<questionList.size()){
  showDialog(questionList.get(i).getTitle,questionList.get(i).getMessage);
  currentQuestion++;
  }else{
   //quiz is over
  }
}
```

Comment: I was working towards something similar. This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you just want to change 1 single layout(created within XML i.e main.xml). In order to do this, make sure  that the class your working on is pointing to that layout. From there (assuming your using an Event listener for when the user submits an answer) you can change do as you want by the following:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); // references the txt XML element
```

and in your Event listener, if the answer is correct then change(Have i be a global variable thats initially set to 0).

```
if(i<arrayList.size()){
     txt.setText(arrayList.get(++i));
}else{
     txt.setText("You Finished");
}
```

From there, in the else statement, you can change arrayLists and reset i to 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the positive, neutral, and negative buttons; then you may have problems with multiple dialogs.  Try defining a customized layout with your own TextViews, ListViews, and Buttons.  You can implement listeners and everything else like a regular layout.  Then just pass your customized layout to the dialog through `AlertDialog.Builder.setView()`.

**PS** If you include code examples of what you are currently doing we can provided answers that are less vague.